# How to put a number only validation

Tags: javascript, php, html

I want to have a number validation on my contact number input. I'm new so I don't have an idea on how to please help.

My current validation is for the field being empty only and it works.

no formatting needed, I just want only numbers to be accepted when I hit the submit button and there will be a message "Numbers only" etc.

```
if(empty(trim($_POST["contact"]))){
        $contact_err = "Please enter a contact number.";
    }  else {
      $contact = trim($_POST["contact"]);
    }
```

Comment: Do you want to check if is a int value for example or do you want to check if is a telephone number with a specific format?

Comment: Use regular expression

Comment: no formatting needed, I just want only numbers to be accepted when I hit the submit button and there will be a message "Numbers only" etc.

Comment: is_numeric  Finds whether a variable is a number or a numeric string  From php.net

Comment: Please add details to the question as an edit no as a comment.

Comment: You could use `filter_var()` using `FILTER_VALIDATE_INT` to validate if a variable contains only INT

Comment: thank you guys esp to you @Sfili_81

Answer (score 3):

Probably worth using [is_numeric()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-numeric.php) to work out whether the value is a number or not, for example:

```
$contact = '';
if (empty($_POST['contact'])) {
    $contact_error = 'Please enter a contact number.';
} elseif (!is_numeric($_POST['contact'])) {
    $contact_error = 'Please enter a number';
} else {
    $contact = trim($_POST['contact']);
}
```

To clean this up a bit, you could probably do something like the following:

```
$contact = $_POST['contact'];
if (empty($contact) || !is_numeric($contact)) {
    $contactError = 'Please enter a numeric contact number';
} else {
    // With how your code us currently organised, this will have to
    // live in an else branch, as otherwise a notice will be thrown if
    // $_POST['contact'] does not exist
    $contact = trim($contact);
}
```

As a note, `is_numeric()` will also be true for string numbers, i.e. `'1'`. If that's not what you want, then you will potentially want another approach, such as `FILTER_VAR` as suggested in the comments, which you can find `FILTER_VALIDATE_INT` documentation on [here](http://php.net/manual/en/filter.filters.validate.php).

Comment: Thanks Mikey this works. I checked the php.net seems no way for this type of validation for email.

Comment: If you want to validate an email which is generally a bit of a pain because of the variety in emails, you can use `filter_var($variable, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL);`